# Writing spatial data from R into MS SQL Server using sf::st_write()

Tags: r, sql-server, gis, r-sf

I am creating a database for a large monitoring project.  I have already set up the schema on the database and am now trying to populate the tables.  I am using R's `DBI::` package to transfer data from R to SQL.  I have been successful in transferring all datatype except for my spatial data.  For the tabular data I have been using `DBI::dbWriteTable()`  However, from scouring other posts, it seems like loading spatial data is better done using the `sf::st_write()` function in the `sf::` package.  However, I am getting several errors:

1. In my local instance of SQL Server, I am getting an error that I am not providing a valid instance of datatype geometry.  The reproducible example below will throw this error.
2. On my network instance of SQL Server, I am getting an error `Invalid object name 'spatial_ref_sys'`  Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce this error with example data.

N.B.: In the code below, you will need to replace the name of your local instance of sql server in the connection strings

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(DBI)
library(sf)
library(spData)

##Getting Example Data from R's spData package##
data("us_states")

##Creating a test database in a local instance of MS SQL Server##
con<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
               server=localsqlserver;trusted_connection=yes")

dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE DATABASE test;")
dbDisconnect(con)

##Changing the connection string to connect directly to test database##
con2<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
               server=localsqlserver;database=test;trusted_connection=yes")

##Writing tabular data to new table in test##
DF<-us_states_df
dbWriteTable(con2, "States", DF)

##Adding a column for spatial data##
dbSendQuery(con2, "ALTER TABLE dbo.States ADD geom geometry")

##Writing spatial data to new column##
geom_tmp<-us_states$geometry
geom<-st_transform(geom_tmp, "+init=epsg:2992")
st_write(obj=geom, dsn=con2, layer = Id(schema="dbo", table="States"), driver="MSSQLSpatial", append=TRUE)
```

My goal at the end of the day is simply to add the spatial data in `geom` to the `geom` column in `test.dbo.states`  I am open to other avenues that might accomplish this.  Thanks in advance for any help.
Take Care,
-Sean

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think sf_write and dbWriteTable (the former being a short for the latter) are conversions from R to PostgeSQL. From your description it sounds like you are using a normal SQL db–could this be the source of the problem? I've made some good experience with `pgInsert(con, name, data.frame, geom, overwrite = TRUE)` from the `rpostgis` package in such applications, but then again this works afaik also only for Postgresql dbs. PS: you might want to consider posting this @ gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Krenz,  I think that `st_write()` allows you to set a specific driver for writing to MSSQL, but I think you're right that it was intended for POSTGIS.  I think I have found a solution (which I published below).  Do you think it is still worth cross-posting on SE?

Comment: Hi Sean, while I agree that your answer works, it is more of a workaround rather than a proper solution. Would be good to get to the source of your problem. Unfortunately, I don't have a Microsoft SQL database to trial this, but I am sure there are plenty of people working with this setup on SE–so yes, I think it is still worth posting there. Might result in a cleaner and potentially faster workflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much tinkering I think I found the solution.  Admittedly it's a bit of a workaround, but it isn't too ugly.  Instead of trying to write a single column, I wrote the entire table using `sf::st_write()`. Importantly, while I could not find a way to write geometries directly into SQL, I found out that I could write a Well-Known-Text to SQL. Once it was in the SQL database I used the `geometery::STGeomFromText()` stored procedure to convert from WKT to geometry.  Below is the updated code:

N.B.: Change the server to the name of your sql server instance in the connection strings below for reproducibility

```
##Loading Necessary Packages##
library(DBI)
library(sf)
library(spData)

##Getting Example Data from R's spData package##
data("us_states")

##Creating a test database in a local instance of MS SQL Server##
con<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
               server=localsqlserver;trusted_connection=yes")

dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE DATABASE test;")
dbDisconnect(con)

##Changing the connection string to connect directly to test database##
con2<-dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string="driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
               server=localsqlserver;database=test;trusted_connection=yes")

##Writing tabular data to new table in test##
DF<-as.data.frame(us_states)
geom<-DF$geometry
DF[,"geom"]<-st_as_text(st_transform(geom,"+init=epsg:2992"))

##Writing table to database##
dbWriteTable(con2, Id(schema="dbo", table="States"), DF[,-7])

##Writing a SQL Statement to create new column with geometry datatype##
##Adding a column for spatial data##
dbSendQuery(con2, "ALTER TABLE dbo.States ADD geom2 geometry")

##Writing spatial data to new column##
dbSendQuery(con2, "UPDATE dbo.States
            Set geom2 = geometry::STGeomFromText(geom, 2992)")

##Dropping the WKT column##
dbSendQuery(con2, "ALTER TABLE dbo.States
            DROP COLUMN geom")

##View the results##
DB<-dbGetQuery(con2, "SELECT * FROM dbo.States")
DB
```